# How to use LIKE in SQL Query (SAP B1)?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sapb1

How can I use LIKE in SQL Query for example

```
Select T0.[U_Tds] FROM HEM1 T0 where  T0.[toDate] LIKE '%YEAR($[HEM1.toDate])'
```

Sorry, I have user defined field of taken days(U_Tds), so I want to get list of all days taken in same year in user defined value

Please anyone can help me

Comment: You need to give a lot more information about what you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: What data is stored in the HEM1 table in Business One? You will have to give more information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's extremely unlikely you would use `LIKE` (which is a string related feature) against dates. Much more likely that there are date functions to use instead.

Also, if that query requires a date range, you want to avoid functions anyway. Just compare the date column to 2 date constants. e.g.

```
SELECT T0.[FromDate] 
FROM HEM1 T0 
WHERE T0.[toDate] >= '2017-01-01' and T0.[toDate] < '2018-01-01'
```

This will give a whole year of data without needing one function call for each row in the table.

The syntax above will work with SQL Server, but a safer format for date literals in SQL Server is:

```
SELECT T0.[FromDate] 
FROM HEM1 T0 
WHERE T0.[toDate] >= '20170101' and T0.[toDate] < '20180101'
```

Please note that dates are NOT stored in a human readable format. They are actually stored as numbers, and converted into strings so that we humans can read them. That's why you don't use like here. Dates are inherently numeric, but LIKE is inherently about strings. e.g. you may be assuming dates are stored in tis fashion '2018-01-01' and so like '2018%' will work. But it wont. To do that you would have to convert every date into a string first e.g.

```
where convert(varchar(4), T0.[toDate] ,112) = '2018'-- very inefficient!

or

where format(T0.[toDate],'yyyy') = '2018' -- very inefficient!
```

Answer (score 0):

`YEAR` is a function, the result you can then concatenate with the `%`

```
Select T0.[FromDate] FROM HEM1 T0 where  T0.[toDate] LIKE concat('%',YEAR($[HEM1.toDate]))
```

Comment: It gives the following error message 1). [Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 10.0][SQL Server]Incorrect syntax near '|'. 2). [Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 10.0][SQL Server]Statement 'Received Alerts' (OAIB) (s) could not be prepared.

Comment: the concatenation symbol `||` isn't supported by SQL Server, but please don't use like against date information.

Comment: @SchadrackRurangwa To avoid misunderstandings you should also say which dbms you use. then use the `concat` function or better the suggestion of @Used_by_already

Comment: I use SQL 2012, Thank you